Add records to SharePoint list from Excel Table using VBA coding
I have found the below code from this site:
Add records to SharePoint list from Excel VBA using shared link
It seems to work but I get an error of "Excel VBA Automation Error Exception Occurred" and it closes my Excel 365 down.  I've searched MS and found https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-vba-automation-error-help/7ccb46af-ea45-459b-91e3-66c614425cbf  which says to add a reference to AccessibilityCplAdmin 1.0 Type Library which I did but I'm still getting this error.  I'll contact MS as well, but if anyone has any ideas why I'd be getting this error or how to fix it, please let me know.  Thanks.
Below is my code, and I have validated my DATABASE connection string:
Sub AddItem()
' Requires a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 6.0 Libray" to insert a record into a sharepoint list "AccessLog"
' Requires a reference to AccessibilityCplAdmin 1.0 Type Library
    Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim mySQL As String

    Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
   ‘Renewal is the name of my table
    mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [Renewal];"

    With cnt ' See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/

'Writes only
.ConnectionString = _
      "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" _
    & "DATABASE=http://mysharepointsite.com/documents/;LIST={5999B8A0-0C2F-4D4D-9C5A-D7B146E49698};"
        .Open
    End With

    rst.Open mySQL, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    rst.AddNew
        rst.Fields("RequestType") = "RequestType"
        rst.Fields("Group") = "Group"
        rst.Fields("Requester") = "Requester"
        rst.Fields("RequestDate") = "RequestDate"
        rst.Fields("Unit") = "Unit"
        rst.Fields("Full VIN") = "Full VIN"
        rst.Fields("State") = "State"
        rst.Fields("Plate Number") = "Plate Number"
        rst.Fields("Vehicle needs sticker (X)") = "Vehicle needs sticker (X)"
        rst.Fields("Vehicle needs plate (X)") = "Vehicle needs plate (X)"
        rst.Fields("Comments") = "Comments"
    rst.Update ' commit changes to SP list

    If CBool(rst.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rst.Close
    If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close
    
    
    MsgBox "Your submission has been received."
End Sub

I just need assistance with the error of "Excel VBA Automation Error Exception Occurred".  Why is it occurring and how do I fix it?

Which line raises the error ? Use F8 to single step program. Does the message box at the end appear.

You don't need to query any records in order to add a new one, so you could consider updating your SQL to something like "SELECT * FROM [Renewal] where False;"

The error is on the line: rst.Open mySQL, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

Thank you Tim, I've changed my SELECT query as you mentioned above.  I'm still getting the same error however.

Try rst.Open "Renewal", cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable

I think the issue is the connect, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.   I'm using the connection from the website https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/  using the write connection Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=http://mysharepointsite.com/documents/;LIST={5999B8A0-0C2F-4D4D-9C5A-D7B146E49698};  with my company info and list based on the settings url.  My list has % where there are - but I've tried it both ways.  The error has changed to can't connect to SharePoint site.  Any ideas would be helpful.  Thanks

The error was the connection string.  This is resolved.
